# Software for $S$-unit equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, computational-number-theory, computer-algebra, magma, sage

Is there any implementation available of an algorithm which solves in full generality the $S$-unit equation $x+y=1$ in a number field? It seems that Magma solves $ax+by=c$ but only in the algebraic integers, while Sage solves $x+y=1$ with $x,y$ $S$-integers, but only for $S$ the set of primes over a fixed rational primes. Is that true? Is there any other implementation available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This SageMath implementation promises the full generality you are seeking:

[A robust implementation for solving the S-unit equation and several applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00977)

See also this [Phys.Org](https://phys.org/news/2019-04-centuries-old-mathematical-puzzles.html) announcement.

Comment: Thanks, that is true indeed. I figured out the problem is that I was using the code K<i>=QuadraticField(-1) instead of K<i>=NumberField(x^2+1), and using the former it gives an error if you try to compute solutions for S a set of primes of different residue characteristic.